# How to get articles which are part of the same group

Tags: mysql

I want to retrieve variants of the same article which are part of the same group. DBM is MySQL 5.7.

There are 2 tables:

1. articles
2. articles_group

Table articles has the fields:

```
article_id | title
1            first product
2            second prod
3            3rd prod
4            4th example
```

Table articles_groups:

```
group_id | article_id
1          1
1          2
1          3
2          4
```

In this example I would like to retrieve all other articles which are in the same group as article 1. So that would be article 2 and 3.

My best shot, but somehow pretty complex:

```
SELECT 
    art.article_id, 
    model
FROM 
    articles art
INNER JOIN 
    articles_group art_g ON art.article_id = art_g.article_id
WHERE art_g.group_id = (
    SELECT ag.group_id
    FROM articles a
    INNER JOIN articles_group ag ON a.article_id = ag.article_id
    WHERE a.article_id = 1
)
```

How can I retrieve all other articles which belong to the same group of given article in an easy way? I can still change the shema if there is a better setup.

Comment: I simplified the example which should now be very precise. Please "unhold" the question.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your given article is 1. To get all articles in same group of given article, you can use `subquery` to get `group_id` of given article. Then use outer query to get all articles in same group.

```
SELECT a.article_id, a.title
FROM articles a
JOIN articles_groups g ON a.ref_id = g.ref_id
WHERE g.group_id = (
    SELECT g.group_id
    FROM articles a
    JOIN articles_groups g ON a.ref_id = g.ref_id
    WHERE a.article_id = '1'
)
```

Comment: Thank you @Samir. I edited the question as the case now is simpler with two tables, however I could not abstract your answer to fit the altered question. Can you help?